# how i show a listview of object with dynamic keys using retrofit2 , GSON , POJO?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, pojo, gson

```
{
  "res": true,
  "data": {
    "5a869f0561f6c232bc9d23db": {
      "Id": "5a869f0561f6c232bc9d23dd",
      "isModerator": false,
      "Name": "AAA",
    },
    "5a869f5a61f6c232bc9d23df": {
       "Id": "5a869f0561f6c232bc9d23dd",
      "isModerator": false,
      "Name": "BBB",

    },
    "5a869be761f6c232bc9d23ca": {
       "Id": "5a869f0561f6c232bc9d23dd",
      "isModerator": false,
      "Name": "CCC",

    },
    "5a86a7358bd74b265621d710": {
      "Id": "5a869f0561f6c232bc9d23dd",
      "isModerator": false,
      "Name": "DDD",
    }
.....
.....
  },
  "logo": "",
  "dateFormat": "f3",
  "globalValidation": {
    "rejectRequest": "Request declined.",
    "acceptRequest": "Request accepted. Please login again to be able to access the new Circle."

  }
}
```

In the above json the numeric key inside "data" object is dynamic. So how do i make a pojo for this json because it may be vary on next response .so how could i show in listview.i'm using retrofit2 in which we have to call userDTO in which we have to defined all models so how can i so in a list.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me you can also try this.

You can get your Json Object dynamic keys By using this

```
try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if (jsonObject.getBoolean("res") == true) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
                    for (String key : iterate(jsonObject1.keys())) {
                        Log.e("In Loop", key);


                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and the method is

```
private <T> Iterable<T> iterate(final Iterator<T> i) {
        return new Iterable<T>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<T> iterator() {
                return i;
            }
        };
    }
```

And create you pojo for   `Id, isModerator` and for `Name`
 and set values in this from your `loop`.

Let me know if it works for you or any other issue in this.

Comment: This example which you shown is ok when you normally call the response from api and handle the response after that but in my case -
I am using retrofit2 library in which i call the api like  this 
mcall.enqueue(new Callback<UserDTO>){}
UserDTO is model class in which we defined models with help of jsontopojo converter
in userDTO data object will convert with key name which i dont want. i want that data will show in list. 
if i change data to list<data> in model class then it will show me a error.